# User-scope configurations settings are lost when I copy the bin folder to another location

Tags: c#, wpf, application-settings

I am developing a WPF application in which I would like to store user-scope configurations settings. 
My only problem is that when I copy the folder containing the application to another location, it generates a new user.config file to be read/write losing all previous settings the user had already set.
If possible, I would also like to store those settings in a file under the .exe folder and read/write from it without having to code the methods for it.

I am also open to suggestions as if there is another simpler way to do this.

UPDATE: Storing the auto-generated user.config (using method `Properties.User.Default.Save();`) in user folders is an ok solution for me, but what is bothering me is that if I copy the bin folder to desktop for example it will generate another file and wont read from the previous one. Another issue is that would be better to put the config file next to the .exe file. I don't really mind the configurations to become available to all users or if they all share the configurations.

SOLVED: Thanks for the help in figuring out a solution, I ended up using the config file generated in app's bin folder(app.exe.config) and to interact with it the ConfigurationManager Class.

```
To open Configuration config=ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
To save config.Save();
To read config.AppSettings.Settings[<property>].Value;
To add config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(<property>,<value>);
To write config.AppSettings.Settings[<property>] = <value>;
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Keeping the config file under the exe folder could be ok, if that is the question.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect fit (well, aside from the file location) for Isolated Storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Assuming you want your application to be well behaved, you shouldn't be storing user level settings within the application folder.  Indeed, users shouldn't even have write access to that folder (this is why Windows now pops up the UAC prompts).  [Application and User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are one method to do this, but you'll still have an issue if you move the application to another machine - you'll need a way to export/import the user settings.

Comment: user-scope configuration in the application folder sounds weird to me.

Usually, I store the user-scope config in Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) which leads to "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming"